# Conditional Logpoint in Chrome Devtools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

If there a way to do a **`Conditional Logpoint`** in Chrome Devtools?

- I KNOW how to add a *logpoint* or a *conditional breakpoint*;
- I DON'T KNOW if is there a way to add a **conditional logpoint** (a logpoint logging only when a specific condition is meet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to add a *conditional logpoint* in Chrome Devtools.

The workaround is to add a *non-breaking conditional **breakpoint*** with `console.log`:

```js
foo.bar===123 && console.log('foo!', foo)
```

The result of this expression is always falsy: either `false` (for the condition) or `undefined` (for console.log) so the breakpoint doesn't trigger and only prints the message on condition.

Comment: not a logpoint but this is the closest thing we've got. I asked about this on the Chromium bug tracker and this is also the solution they suggested. They said that it will probably not be implemented to avoid unnecessary clutter or something along those lines

Answer (score 1):

What I have been doing is creating a log message that throws an error given a specified condition. Any code in the logpoint that throws prevents the log from making it to the console but will not have an effect the original, running code. You can abuse this to make what is effectively a conditional logpoint with a format such as:

```
<condition> ? <message to log> : <expression that throws>
```

For example:

```
this.enabled ? `Enabled sproket's name is ${this.name}` : null.x
```

This will only log "Enabled sproket's name is ..." if the `enabled` property is true. If not, the logpoint will evaluate `null.x` which throws, preventing anything from getting logged at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to reduce the noise in the console, you can tag the useful/interesting messages with some text, and set the console filter to show only the one's you want...  Not great; would be better if the condition in the 'conditional breakpoint' was applied to the logpoint

Comment: I would like to log ONLY if a condition is meet, is not bout the noise, if I log every time on the same line I can't distinguish a specific situation.

Comment: that was the point of marking the interesting/useful 'distinguished' log message with something you can discriminate with the search.  Instead of *you* trying to eye-ball all those lines, let search/match to the hard work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want **breaking conditional Logpoint**:
the way to do it is to add a *breaking* conditional breakpoint with console.log

```
foo && (console.log('foo!'), foo)
```

simply said, it triggers the breakpoint and logs only if *foo* exits.

```
let foo = false // or null or undefined
```

> false
> // (doesn't trigger the breakpoint)

```
let foo = true
```

> foo!
> true
> // (logs 'foo!' in console and triggers the breakpoint)

Comment: please read carreluffy the OP "I KNOW how to do a logpoint or a conditional breakpoint"...

Comment: i know, you were asking for conditional logpoint, which to my understanding, based on previous answer marked as correct the author of that answer stated that there's 
| no way to add a conditional logpoint in Chrome Devtools.
additionally they are giving you an answer with specifically mentioned "a non-breaking" conditional logpoint.
I'm giving you exactly what you asked for so i don't understand where's the problem with my answer?

edit: i named it wrong, it's obviously Breaking Conditional *Logpoint*